# Discord.js Sorting through all text channels on a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'cleartextchats',
 description:
  'clears desired amount of text chats created by the bot. usage: cleartextchats <amount>',
 execute(message, args) {
  var channelAmount = args[0];
  console.log('executing cleartextchats');
  for (var i = 0; i < channelAmount; i++) {
   var textChat = message.guild.channels.cache
    .filter((ch) => ch.type === 'text')
    .find(
     (targetch) => targetch.topic == 'volturnbot' && targetch.deleted == false
    );
   message.channel.send(`deleting ` + textChat.name);
   textChat.delete();
  }
 },
};
```

The for loop does not advance past the first deleted channel.
I presume this is because the cache does not update unless I use a different/new message but the command is supposed to run from a message. I cant think of a way to implement this that would work for any amount of channels.

Currently whenever my bot creates text channels it updates the topic to include "volturnbot" so that it can delete its own channels without a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `guild.channels.cache` returns a collection, you have to use `.array()`
also, instead of finding a single channel and then searching through the same cache, put all channels in a single array and loop through that.

```
    var channelAmount = Number(args[0]);
    var textChats = message.guild.channels.cache
        .filter((ch) => ch.type === 'text' && ch.topic === 'volturnbot')
        .array()
        
    for (var i = 0; i <= channelAmount; i++) {
        message.channel.send("deleting " + textChats[i].name)
        //textChats[i].delete()
    }
```

Comment: Note that you need to check for `i < channelAmount` in the `for` loop, not `i <= channelAmount`. For example, if `channelAmount` is equal to 1 (meaning we want to delete 1 channel), the loop will execute once at `i == 0` and another time at `i == 1` (meaning 2 channels are deleted, instead of only 1). Change the `<=` to `<` and then this answer will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

> I presume this is because the cache does not update unless I use a different/new message but the command is supposed to run from a message.

I believe that assumption is correct. It is probably because the `channel.deleted` property is still `false` even after you delete the channel in the for loop, since there is probably a slight delay associated with channel deletion. There are two solutions I can think of:

A) Instead of using a `for` loop, you could perhaps use `setInterval` as a loop with a delay of 1000 milliseconds or so (might have to increase or decrease that depending on what works). You would need to create two new variables: one to contain the `setInterval` loop, and another to keep track of how many iterations of the loop have occurred. When the iterations variable is equal to the channelAmount variable, that would be when you use `return clearInterval(intervalVariable)` where intervalVariable is the variable containing the loop. (This is assuming a timeout gives the cache enough time to update after the channel is deleted).

B) Loop through the cached text channels instead of fetching one channel from the cache each time. Example:

```
var channelAmount = Number(args[0]);
console.log("executing cleartextchats")

var channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.deleted == false && ch.type === 'text' && ch.topic && ch.topic.match("volturnbot"));
var iterations = 0;

for (var textChat of channels) {
    iterations++;
    message.channel.send(`deleting ` + textChat.name)
    textChat.delete()

    if (iterations == channelAmount) break;
}
```

Honestly I prefer option B, and I am positive option B would work much better in terms of what you want to achieve here. You also mentioned that the channel topic "includes" the phrase "volturnbot", I'm not sure if that indicates the description could be more than exactly "volturnbot" so I made option B use `topic.match("volturnbot")` for that reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I almost completely gave up on this problem.

However, it seems that the match method is giving an error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
    at message.guild.channels.cache.filter.ch`

There are channels on the testing server that do not have a topic, and I guess their topic is equal to null which is giving this error.

Comment: no matter what sorting method I am using right now, it seems that the `topic` value is always undefined or something.

``        for (let channel of message.guild.channels.cache) {
            if (channel.topic && channel.topic.includes("volturnbot")) message.channel.send(channel.name);
        }``
if it has to read through `channel.topic` it just returns undefined, and that goes the same for any channel it seems.

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure why that occurs. I found questions on stack overflow that have the same problem, but their answers aren't very clear. If you do end up finding a solution to that, let me know and I will update the answer to include it.

Comment: You might also want to try something like `console.log(channel.topic)` or `console.log(Object.keys(channel))` to make sure the channel objects we have contain the 'topic' property.

Comment: Found out that `channels.cache` returns a collection instead of an array, so you have to convert with `.array()`, fixed it in a different answer and it works

Comment: You can loop through collections just like you can loop through arrays, using the for/of loop in my answer. I am not sure why converting the channel cache to an array fixed your issue, but if it works, it works.